# How to refer macro to cell range in current sheet?

Tags: excel, vba

I recorded a macro to create graphs on a worksheet.
The data are organized in the same way in all the sheets of the workbook, therefore I would like to generalize the macro so that it can be used on every sheet (or if it is possible to batch through the worksheets).

The code looks like this:

```
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-57
Range("C5:C65").Select
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
ActiveChart.ChartType = xlLine
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("fr_1!$C$5:$C$65")
ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).Select
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = "=fr_1!$A$5:$A$65"
```

Having recorded the macro on fr_1 I now have that reference in the 5th and last line, while I would like to have a general reference to the active sheet.

How do I do this?

Comment: Your three lines of code ending in `.Select` have no effect at all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can:

```
Dim aSheet As Worksheet
For Each aSheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    With aSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Chart
        .ChartType = xlLine
        .SetSourceData Source:=aSheet.Range(aSheet.Name & "!$C$5:$C$65")
        .SeriesCollection(1).XValues = "=" & aSheet.Name & "!$A$5:$A$65"
    End With
Next
```

If you want to iterate the manually selected sheets change to `for each asheet in activewindow.selectedsheets`

To manually filter by name;

```
Dim aSheet As Worksheet
For Each aSheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    select case aSheet.name
        case "sheet1", "sheet50", "sheet999"   
            With aSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Chart
                .ChartType = xlLine
                .SetSourceData Source:=aSheet.Range(aSheet.Name & "!$C$5:$C$65")
                .SeriesCollection(1).XValues = "=" & aSheet.Name & "!$A$5:$A$65"
            End With
    end select
Next
```

Comment: The two range lines should be `.SetSourceData Source:=aSheet.Range("'" & aSheet.Name & "'!$C$5:$C$65")` and
`.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = "='" & aSheet.Name & "'!$A$5:$A$65"` else this code will fail for any character that induces the `'` in sheet names (for example a space)

Comment: Seems to be a very good solution but is there a way to make it work only on a selection of sheets, maybe grouping them?

Comment: Updated above (I don't think you can create "permanent" sheet ranges, you would need to ctrl+click each sheet then run the function)

Comment: @AlexK see above, you can set up a "permanent" sheet range in code without selection. cheers.

Comment: Yep thats true, but I meant doing in via the UI so as not to have to hard code sheet names (a ctrl+click group dissapears as soon as another tab is selected)

Comment: Trying to run the first part with the ".selectedsheets" line is giving me a runtime error 1004 on the 3rd line.

Comment: Woops, the first line after `For Each aSheet In ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets` needs to be `aSheet.Select`

Answer (score 2):

You can

- add the desired sheets to an Array and just access the sheets you want to place charts on. This code only runs on the three sheet names supplied by `Arrshts = Array("Sheet1", "Sheet3", "MySheet With Space")`
- skip the potential naming issue by referring just to local ranges

[**Updated** - added error handling for potential invalid sheet names]

```
    Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim Arrshts()
    Dim ArrSht
    Dim strOut As String
    Arrshts = Array("Sheet1", "Sheet3", "MySheet With Space")
    For Each ArrSht In Arrshts
    On Error Resume Next
    Set ws = Nothing
    Set ws = Sheets(ArrSht)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Not ws Is Nothing Then
        With Sheets(ArrSht).Shapes.AddChart.Chart
            .ChartType = xlLine
            .SetSourceData Range("$C$5:$C$65")
            .SeriesCollection(1).XValues = Range("$A$5:$A$65")
        End With
    Else
        strOut = strOut & (vbNewLine & ArrSht)
    End If
    Next
    If Len(strOut) > 0 Then MsgBox strOut, , "These array names are incorrect and need adjusting"
    End Sub
```